# select onchange issue

Tags: php, javascript, html

I am working on a brand filter. When I change the brand name from dropdown, I am not getting anything; it seems that no event was triggered.

Below is my code:

```
<select onchange="location.href=[server.url type='fullpage' query='sort=price&brand=$brand']">

<?php 
  $brands = dfr_get_brands_list($category);
foreach ($brands as $brand) : ?>

       <option><?php echo $brand; ?></option>

<?php endforeach; ?>

</select>
```

`[server.url type='fullpage' query='']` returns the full URL of the current page, for example: `http://www.mysite.com/store/category/shoes/`.

Comment: What are you tying to do? What is this supposed to mean: `location.href=[server.url type='fullpage' query='sort=price&brand=$brand']`?

Comment: make sure the returned by [server.url type='fullpage' query='sort=price&brand=$brand'] URL is displayed in single quotes so it reads for example: onchange="location.href='http://www.mysite.com/store/category/shoes/'"

Comment: What is `[server.url type='fullpage' query='sort=price&brand=$brand']`?

Comment: for [server.url type='fullpage' query='price=150-300'] means http://www.mywebsite.com/store/category/shoes/?price=150-300

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not mix JavaScript and PHP. JavaScript runs on the client, PHP runs on the server, they can not run together.

Break the logic out of the HTML tag and make a function, call that function onchange. Cleans up the code so it is easier to read and maintain.

What you need to do is to change the code to add the brand dynamically to the end of the url

```
function gotoPage(){
    var url = "theBaseUrlHere";
    var sel = document.getElementById("yourSelectId");
    var brand = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].text;
    window.location.href = url + "&brand=" + brand;
}
```

Comment: I tried as you said... now event is triggering.. BUT now when I select brand, the url appearing in browser like this: http://domainname.com/storec/clothes/&brand=undefined

I didnt understood why 'undefined' coming instead of brand name..

Any idea..?

Comment: I checked ur code in jsfiddle.. BUt i dont understand why in my case not working..

Comment: Well I can not see your code so I can not tell you. Show what you did exactly.

Comment: bro, iam pretty sure i tested correctly only! , YI, for [server.url type='fullpage' query='price=150-300'] means http://www.mywebsite.com/store/category/shoes/?price=150-300